# How to achieve the use exposure filter of views, head Title Update？

Tags: 7, views

I use the exposed filter on a Drupal 7 website. I want to achieve that when the user clicks on the filter, the head of the title will also output the filtering term.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Add `Taxonomy term: Name` as a field

- Check `Exclude from display`
- Uncheck `Link this field to its taxonomy term page`

2) Click on *Title:* and put `[name]`

[image]