# Change page title

Tags: 8, views, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I've created a view to display products based on the taxonomy vocabulary Categories.
I followed a few how tos and check for answers on drupal.org, here & other websites but none is working.

I would like the title of the view to be the name of taxonomy term displayed.

The Path is : taxonomy/term/%
Contextual filter:
-- When the filter value is NOT in the URL > Provide default value > Taxonomy Term ID from URL
-- When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided > Specify validation criteria > Taxonomy Term ID
--   -- Vocabulary > Categories

To overwrite the title, I have 2 Replacement patterns available :

```
{{ arguments.field_categories_target_id }} == Product: Catégories (field_categories) title
{{ raw_arguments.field_categories_target_id }} == Product: Catégories (field_categories) input
```

The both display the Taxonomy term ID, not the name.

I've tried with other replacement patterns, nothing is displayed.

I'm running Drupal 8.9.13.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

---

This is the .yml file.

```yaml
uuid: cb266220-13c8-434d-8371-cabb6d7af36f
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - commerce_product.commerce_product_type.dropixx
    - core.entity_view_mode.commerce_product.vignette
    - field.storage.commerce_product.field_categories
    - taxonomy.vocabulary.categories
    - taxonomy.vocabulary.marques_cat
  module:
    - commerce
    - commerce_product
    - ds
    - taxonomy
id: taxonomy
label: Taxonomy
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: commerce_product_field_data
base_field: product_id
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 12
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: null
          tags:
            previous: ‹‹
            next: ››
            first: ««
            last: »»
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          quantity: 5
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          row_class: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 vg-box'
          default_row_class: true
          uses_fields: false
      row:
        type: 'ds_entity:commerce_product'
        options:
          relationship: none
          view_mode: vignette
          alternating_fieldset:
            alternating: false
            allpages: false
            item_0: default
            item_1: default
            item_2: default
            item_3: default
            item_4: default
            item_5: default
            item_6: default
            item_7: default
            item_8: default
            item_9: default
          grouping_fieldset:
            group: false
          advanced_fieldset:
            advanced: false
      fields:
        title:
          table: commerce_product_field_data
          field: title
          id: title
          entity_type: null
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        field_categories:
          id: field_categories
          table: commerce_product__field_categories
          field: field_categories
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: entity_reference_label
          settings:
            link: true
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 1
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
        nothing:
          id: nothing
          table: views
          field: nothing
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: true
            text: "<br>title {{ title }}\r\n<br>categories {{ field_categories }}\r\n<br>target id {{ arguments.field_categories_target_id }} "
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: false
          plugin_id: custom
      filters:
        status:
          value: '1'
          table: commerce_product_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: commerce_product
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: commerce_product_field_data
          field: type
          value:
            dropixx: dropixx
          entity_type: commerce_product
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: commerce_entity_bundle
          expose:
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
        field_stock_qty_value:
          id: field_stock_qty_value
          table: commerce_product__field_stock_qty
          field: field_stock_qty_value
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '!='
          value:
            min: ''
            max: ''
            value: '0'
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            placeholder: ''
            min_placeholder: ''
            max_placeholder: ''
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: numeric
        field_marque_target_id:
          id: field_marque_target_id
          table: commerce_product__field_marque
          field: field_marque_target_id
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: or
          value: {  }
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: field_marque_target_id_op
            label: 'Marques :'
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: field_marque_target_id_op
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
            identifier: field_marque_target_id
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
              anonymous: '0'
              administrator: '0'
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          reduce_duplicates: false
          type: select
          limit: true
          vid: marques_cat
          hierarchy: false
          error_message: true
          plugin_id: taxonomy_index_tid
      sorts: {  }
      title: '<none>'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments:
        field_categories_target_id:
          id: field_categories_target_id
          table: commerce_product__field_categories
          field: field_categories_target_id
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: '{{ arguments.field_marque_target_id }}'
          title_enable: true
          title: '{{ arguments.field_categories_target_title }}'
          default_argument_type: taxonomy_tid
          default_argument_options:
            term_page: '1'
            anyall: ','
            node: false
            limit: false
            vids: {  }
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            items_per_page: 25
            override: false
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: true
          validate:
            type: 'entity:taxonomy_term'
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options:
            bundles:
              categories: categories
            access: true
            operation: view
            multiple: 0
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
          plugin_id: numeric
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
        - user
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.commerce_product.field_categories'
  taxonomy_category_contextual:
    display_plugin: page
    id: taxonomy_category_contextual
    display_title: Page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders:
        metatag_display_extender: {  }
      path: taxonomy/term/%
      enabled: true
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
        - user
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.commerce_product.field_categories'
```

Comment: See [my D7 answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220249/27710). Same procedure except in D8/D9 you use `{{ name }}`.

Comment: ThX, but it partially works. Taxonomy Term : name is not available. I'm displaying product fileds. With {{ field_categories }} in the title field, It displays all categories. If I select in Multiple field settings Display 1. It display the first Category title in all categories of the tree.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to solve it programmatically. I show in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298040/27710) how to programmatically alter the view title.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is there any particular reason you are using that filter?

I believe that if you use the "Has Taxonomy Term ID" contextual filter [image: Like so], it will work as you intend it to.

Let me know if i did not understand your question correctly.
Best Regards.

Comment: You understaood right. I am using the Overwrite Title field.
It doesn't work. Nothing is displayed when I add {{ arguments.tid }}. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: That pattern is not one that Views gave you?

Comment: @mChamps I am suggesting also that you should use a different contextual filter, not just the different token. Have you tried that?

Comment: I've created the view from scratch. I am building a shop with Drupal Commerce and I want to be able to navigate with a category hierarchy, so I use Taxonomy. When I click on overwrite title, view gives me 2 replacement patterns. They display the taxonomy ID instead of the Taxonomy Name. How can I use a different contextual filter? It is the only available filter related to Taxonomy.

Comment: You delete the one you have and use the one I suggester. I am sorry if I don't understand what the issue is. Would you mind sharing the whole yml file so that I can get some better insight on your problem and maybe help more actively?